# listing the products of a particular category and having similar name using soap api

Tags: php, magento, soap

I have list of products having similar name say 10 shoes from nike, 10 from reebok and so on. So all the products will start with the name nike, reebok and so( which are all inside a single category called shoes). I need to list the nike shoes alone from the category shoes using soap apis.

```
<?php
$path="http://localhost/magento/";
try{
$proxy=new SoapClient($path.'index.php/api/soap/?wsdl=1');
$sessionId=$proxy->login('apiuser','apikey');
echo $sessionId;
$result=$proxy->call($sessionId,'catalog_category.assignedProducts','4');
print_r($result);
}
catch (SoapFault $e)
{
    $msg = "Could not connect to the site".$e->getMessage();
    echo $msg."<br/>";   
}
?>
```

I tried the above but its listing all the products of that category, Is it possible to send (or add) another arguments so that it will fetch nike shoes alone? Help me to solve this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to not rely on soap to provide the object you desire, but use it to provide the *means* to get the objects you desire.  Here is how to think it out:

1. Ask soap to give you a list of product ids in a category
2. Use that list to load a product collection
3. Filter the product collection based on your needs

If you are writing code that will execute on the same server as magento, simply do the following:

1. Create an attribute set called "Shoes"
2. Create a dropdown attribute called shoe_type and add options for each type of shoe you want to filter on (nike, reebok, whatever). Note the dropdown attribute IDs.
3. Use the following code in a test.php file in your magento root directory.  I've tested it and it works.

The idea is that you are going to create a collection based on what is "IN" a category, and filter them based on certain attributes.

```
    echo "<PRE>";
    umask(0);

    // MAKE SURE TO PUT THIS FILE IN THE RIGHT PLACE (MAGENTO ROOT)
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';

    Mage::app('admin');

    $attributeSetId = '26'; // Your attribute set id (shoes)
    $shoeTypeId = '1'; // The ID of the dropdown item to filter on (taken from the ids of the items you added to the shoe_type attribute

    // Create a collection based on a catalog category. Load category ID 196
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(196)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('shoe_type', $shoeTypeId);

    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        // Write out the useful info!
        var_dump($product->debug());
    }
```

Not only is using this method almost 100 times faster, but you can more clearly work with magento's object model. Soap is more useful for talking from server to server, or if you need a windows machine to talk to your magento linux box (as I do with my sync service).

Comment: Actually this is the one which am using now, I heard that the process will be faster if we use apis and thats why i asked this question.Is it possible to achieve this using apis.?